# Is there a benefit to Rails apps being compiled to slugs outside of Heroku? Can you make a non-Heroku slug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, compilation, slug

Is there a spec, whitepaper, anything at all out there, regarding what a slug is in the Heroku context?  I've always noticed how Heroku compiles Rails apps into slugs, increasing performance, at least within their proprietary environment.

Is there a way to do this outside of Heroku, and/or take advantage of it within a different environment?

Comment: isn't this just a different terminoligy for app? i don't think that they actually "compile" anything...

Comment: Very possible; it's a bit of a "noob" question, admittedly, but I know that every app is capable of "precompiling" in some sense...  For example, the Asset Pipeline added to Rails 3 precompiles "Assets" (minifies javascript and CSS files, combines them into one file for faster loading, etc).  This is stuff set in application config and can be utilized with rake tasks.  And at the other end of the spectrum (and slightly outside the scope of this question), a JRuby app can even be compiled to binary.  So, I wondered if Heroku is doing some magic (that people are overlooking) that would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by John Beynon above, the 'compilation' is another name for the build pack process. When you push your code to Heroku we resolve all depedencies and TGZ the resulting package into a "slug".

The process is open source, with full documentation and links to the various supported buildpacks on our [devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). If you want the technical details of exactly what goes on, refer to the [buildpack api doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api).

We have already seen some [other](http://docs.stackato.com/deploy/buildpack.html) platforms start to adopt buildpacks. It would be great to see anyone who likes adopt them and provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen any documentation aside from [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) but it's not 'compiling' in the traditional sense of the word.

They take the git repo you have pushed your application into, remove the .git directory, clean up unnecessary directories, process .slugignore file to remove any bits you don't need at runtime (like tests etc, etc), they then include dependencies and then create a smaller version of your application which is more easily distributed across the dyno grid. The smaller your slug size the faster it is to scale your application because each dyno you add receives a fresh copy of the 'compiled' slug.

Comment: Great answer; thanks for this. I think that pretty much covers it, assuming there's no magic they're leaving out of public info (perhaps part of their "secret sauce" from a business standpoint?). This may be silly, but for the sake of a noob learning some app/server theory: I wonder if a "compiler" like this couldn't be adapted for non-Heroku apps as part of an open-source project. Sort of a Rails app compiler than makes a "slug" that other servers can run (say, for people hosting their app on EC2 or Linode or some other VPS sort of solution). Could this be useful, or is it a ridiculous idea?

Comment: BTW, I guess the impetus for this question is the brief understanding and remembrance that I have of [HipHop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP), the PHP compiler that Facebook created which transforms PHP source code into C++ and then uses g++ to compile it to machine code, resulting in performance of something like 2-6X improvement.  Obviously this is a bit outside the scope of what I'm asking, but wouldn't such a concept make sense, for Ruby/Rails apps, at some point in the future?  If it became an evolution of Heroku "slug compilation" at Heroku, it might remain secret sauce.

Comment: not secret sauce at all - all open source, they call them buildpacks - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby